# Error extending abstract class from unlocked package

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, unlocked-package

I'm trying to extend an Apex class from an unlocked package (of mine). I was able to declare the Apex Class and save to the org, but when I tried to instantiate an instance of the class in a trigger and call a method from the base class, I get an error.

The logic goes something like the following:

In unlocked package:

```
public abstract with sharing class MyBaseClass {
...
    public virtual void myMethod(){}  
...
}
```

In my sfdx project:

Apex Class definition

```
public with sharing class myClass extends MyBaseClass{
    
...
}
```

Apex Trigger definition:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Lead(...){
   new myClass().myMethod();
}
```

When I try to deploy the trigger to my sandbox I get the following error:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void myMethod() from the type myClass
```

Comment: Does your package have a namespace?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Can you clarify - is the package an unmanaged 1GP or an unlocked 2GP?

Comment: If you `overwrite` the myMethod() in the instantiated class, do you still get the error?

Comment: @PhilW it's an unlocked 2GP.

Comment: Can I suggest you remove the "unmanaged" reference in the question then, please?

Comment: @PhilW done, thank you.